# Get PID of ongoing Python process started via script via systemd

Tags: systemd, process, python

I am using `systemd` to run a shell script at boot, `start.sh`, that eventually starts `main.py`, my program’s main Python script.

I would like to record the PID of `main.py` so it can be programmatically killed later.

I first tried the following, but found that the Python script didn’t stay alive, even though the PID was recorded (note that I’m redirecting error output to a log file).

```
sudo python main.py 2> >(sudo tee /var/log/app.log) &
echo $1 > /tmp/app.pid
```

However, when removing the `&`, the script stays alive, but the PID script never reaches the line where it records the PID.

```
sudo python main.py 2> >(sudo tee /var/log/app.log)
echo $1 > /tmp/app.pid
```

How can I run `main.py` in a way that keeps it alive, but still gives me the PID?

Comment: in your main.py script you can ```import os``` and use ```os.getpid()``` to get the process id of your running script.  You can then print that out to wherever you'd like to record it.  If it's python3, you can ```print(os.getpid(), file=open("<dir>/file.pid", "a"))``` for python2 you'd need to open the file first ```filevar = open("<dir>/file.pid","w")``` then use ```filevar.write(os.getpid())```

Comment: Why don't you use `systemctl` for killing the service? That's what SystemD is for, that we do not search and kill PIDs any more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Fubar’s comment that mentioned `os.getpid()`, I found that `os.getppid()` achieved what I needed, since the parent thread turned out to be the process I needed to kill:

```
PID = str(os.getppid())
with open(‘app.pid’, ‘w’) as file:
    file.write(PID)
```

I then can kill this later in a script with:

```
sudo kill `cat /tmp/app.pid`
```

Note that I’ve got to use `sudo` here since the original python script is run with `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

a simple example , that use `exec`

`exec` replace the current process executable by another executable .

```
sudo bash -c ' echo $$ > /var/run/app.pid ; exec python3 -u /tmp/main.py  > /var/log/app.log 2>&1 '
```

and after you can verify by

```
cat /var/run/app.pid ; ps -ax -o pid,uname,args | grep "^ *$(cat /var/run/app.pid)"
```